# How do I reference variables from higher tiers after filters in JQ?

Tags: jq

Let's say I have a couple thousand Test Kit entries in a data list:

```
[
    {
        "id": "abcde1",
        "data": {
            "type": "COVID19",
            "date": "2020-04-15"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "hijkl1",
        "data": {
            "type": "COVID20",
            "date": "2020-04-02"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "asdf1",
        "data": {
            "type": "COVID19",
            "date": "2020-04-16"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "jkl1",
        "data": {
            "type": "COVID20",
            "date": "2020-04-16"
        }
    }
]
```

Each entry could be any "type".  I want to filter by just "COVID19" AND print the "id":

```
COVID19 asdf1
COVID19 abcde1
```

JQ can easily filter entries that are "COVID19" for me:

```
cat dat.json |jq -r '.[].data |select(.type == "COVID19")'
```

But once I've drilled down in to `.[].data` I can no longer reference `.[].id`.

How do I reference a higher-tier key / value after filtering results?  Is there a shortcut for the root object that is something like an absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I reference variables from higher tiers after filters in JQ?

There are numerous methods, and your choice will probably depend on the specific class of tasks you have in mind.

One technique is to store the item of interest in a jq variable, e.g. along the lines of:

```
.[]
| .id as $id
| .data
| select(.type == "COVID19")
| [.type, $id]
| join(" ")
```

Another technique is to use `paths` and `getpath`.

Still another is to use `tostream`.

Comment: Thanks @Peak.  My first attempt at using a variable confused me because of its placement - `.[].id as $id | .[].data | select(.type == "COVID19") | "\(.type) \($id)"` produced the same `id` over and over again in the output.  Moving it to after the `.[]` displayed the correct id.  Could you note that in your answer?

Comment: I read the manual about `path()` and `getpath()` but I'm still pretty lost as to how to apply it here; if you're willing to write out an example of how to use those to accomplish what I'm doing I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, 
A simpler solution can be just to modify access from `.type` to `.data.type` so there's no need to store variables.

```
.[]
| select(.data.type == "COVID19")
| [.data.type, .id] | join(" ")
```

Comment: I tried this, over the other answer, when dealing with `nmap`'s xml using `xq`. The result was different. (using `join(":")`) I got a single line with `ip:port:port:port:port` instead of various `ip:port` as I wanted, and as @peak answer gave me.